# How does this object 'see' its inherited properties?

Tags: javascript

I've just discovered `__proto__` is not a property of an object. It is an accessor property of `Object.prototype` ([source](https://javascript.info/prototype-methods)). Chrome's console definitely confused me :/.

So when we see something like:

[image]

And we do something like this:

`o = {}; o.valueOf()`

What is happening step-by-step? I'm not quite sure what role Object.prototype.`__proto__` has to play now and if it helps in any way.

I am re-reading MDN documentation and articles I've saved but I would greatly appreciate a step-by-step explanation in the case of my `o` example, in the mean-time.

**My guess:**

I know that `Object.prototype.__proto__` is an accessor property that will return a 'special, hidden' [[prototype]] 'internal slot'/property.

In the case of `o = {}; o.valueOf()`, I suspect `o` somehow has the ability to access `Object.prototype.__proto__` which will return/reference `Object.prototype`. This doesn't make sense to me at all (if you can see `Object.prototype.__proto__` why not just see `Object.prototype` so I'm sure it's not right.

Comment: Make a reference here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: `o.valueOf()` triggers a `[[Get]]` operation on `o`, and it uses a `[[GetPrototypeOf]]` operation to access the `[[Prototype]]` internal property without using `__proto__`. `__proto__` is just a JS-land accessor for doing the same (triggering a `[[GetPrototypeOf]]`)

Comment: Thanks @FZs. Where is that `[[Get]]` operation coming from. Did you have a look at my 'guess'? Does `[[Get]] have anything to do Object.prototype.__proto__`? Why have you given it double-brackets? Is there a link or diagram that you could point me to? I just need everything spelled out clearly

Comment: The `[[Get]]` operation is triggered by the *property access* operators, `.` and `[]`. `[[Get]]` and `__proto__` uses the same internal method for getting the `[[Prototype]]`. `something.__proto__` also uses a `[[Get]]` (and therefore `[[GetPrototypeOf]]`) to look up the `__proto__` property (located on `Object.prototype`), then, the `__proto__` getter triggers another `[[GetPrototypeOf]]`, and returns its result. Names in double brackets is the conventional notation for internal methods and slots, that can't be directly accessed from JS-land. Reading: https://tc39.es/ecma262/ (hard to read)

Comment: I wanted to link [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots), but wasn't successful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is happening step-by-step? I'm not quite sure what role `Object.prototype.__proto__` has to play now.

The `.__proto__` accessor on `Object.prototype` plays absolutely no role in the property access. You're not using it explicitly, and you shouldn't do.

When you access `o.valueOf`, the engine first checks whether the object `o` has an own `valueOf` property. It doesn't in your case. Then it goes to the prototype chain, i.e. the engine does access the internal *[[prototype]]* slot to find `Object.prototype`, which `o` is inheriting from. This object *does* have a `valueOf` property, so the engine does access it and use the function value it is holding. The result of the property access is then called.

The engine can directly access the internal slot, it doesn't need to use any language-level entity. In the same way, the devtools debugger, the `Object.getPrototypeOf` function or the `.__proto__` getter can access these internal data structures, as that's how the engine implemented them to work.